# For $0 \le x \le \frac{π}{4}$,let $f(x) = \sin(x) + \cos(x)$. Find the infimum of $f(x)$ over the interval $x \in [0,\frac{π}{4}]$

Tags: real-analysis

For $0 \le x \le \frac{π}{4}$,let $f(x) = \sin(x) + \cos(x)$. Find the infimum of $f(x)$ over the
interval $x \in [0,\frac{π}{4}]$.i found the critical points and the second derivative but it seems there is no infimum for this function in the defined interval.Am i right ? or should i have to use an other method?

Comment: differentiated found the critical point applied it in the second differential

Comment: No infimum for a bounded continuous function on a compact interval? Really? Just an hint: an infimum is not necessarily a critical point, even if the function is differentiable everywhere, as here. There is another possibility that should be cristal clear if you draw the curve.

Comment: Thers *must* be a minimum and a maximum, because $f$ is *continuous* on a *compact* interval, so by Weierstrass's theorem it must reach its extremes.

Comment: Here "compact interval" just means bounded interval in the real numbers.  The second derivative is not terribly important.  Compare the values at endpoints and at critical points, and choose the smallest of these.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt2\sin\left(\dfrac\pi4+x\right)$$

$$0\le x\le\dfrac\pi4\iff\dfrac\pi4\le x+\dfrac\pi4\le\dfrac\pi2$$

$$\implies\sin\dfrac\pi4\le\sin\left(\dfrac\pi4+x\right)\le\sin\dfrac\pi2=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Note $f'(x) = \cos x - \sin x$. Since $\cos x > \sin x$ in $[0, \frac {\pi}{4})$ $f$ is monotone increasing in $[0, \frac{\pi}{4})$, which implies we have a minimum of $1$ at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

### Using trigonometric identities:

Recall that

$$a \sin x + b \cos x = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \sin (x + \varphi)$$

where $\tan \varphi = \frac ba$. Thus,

$$f(x) = \sin x + \cos x = \sqrt{2} \sin (x + \frac {\pi}4).$$

$$x \in [0, \frac {\pi}4] \Rightarrow (x + \frac {\pi}4) \in [\frac {\pi}4, \frac {\pi}2].$$

Observe that $f(x) = \sin x$ is monotonically increasing on $[\frac {\pi}4, \frac {\pi}2]$, thus

\begin{align}
f(x)_{min} & = f(0) \\
 & = \sqrt 2 \sin \frac {\pi}4 \\
 & = 1. \\
\end{align}

### Using calculus:

$$f(x) = \sin x + \cos x.$$

On the interval $[0, \frac {\pi}4)$, $f'(x) = \cos x - \sin x \gt 0$, and $f'(\frac {\pi}4) = 0$, thus,

\begin{align}
f(x)_{min} & = f(0) \\
 & = \sqrt 2 \sin \frac {\pi}4 \\
 & = 1. \\
\end{align}